# Formalization of finite processes

Tags: proof-writing, induction, solution-verification

So, this question is about a recurring pattern I've noticed in some proofs, to which I've never actually seen a rigorous justification. I'm talking about finite, induction-like processes of definitions and proofs. My main goal with this post is to learn whether there is a
specific name for this technique, or if it belongs to a specific field of study in proof theory/foundations, so I can find out whether it is a valid way of proving statements and why.

Consider, for example, the following proof in Axler's "Linear Algebra Done Right":

[image: Axler]

Here, the author does some kind of finite process that looks like induction, which I believe is not induction *per se*, since the process ends in a finite step $m$. Is this proof rigorous in some sense?

I do believe that this technique has something to do with some kind of "bounded induction" (I already asked a question about that at: [Is there such thing as "bounded" Induction?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3866332/is-there-such-thing-as-bounded-induction)).

*Note*: I actually sketched a proof similar to Axler's using only definition by induction and "bounded induction" (that is just the standard induction, if my reasoning is correct). First, you define a sequence $(L_1,L_2,\dots)$ of lists of vectors such that, for each $i\leq m$, $L_i$ coincides with the list of vectors in step $i$ of Axler's proof, and only then you prove the stuff about each $L_i$: that, for $i\leq m$, $L_i$ is linearly independent and that $e_1,\dots,e_i$ are in $L_i$. But this proof seems to be subtler and, essentially, not quite the same as the original one, since Axler defines the lists and proves stuff about them in the same process. What I am looking for is a way to "translate" this argument of the steps into concrete mathematical objects.

Comment: It is rigorous in any reasonable sense. If you’re asking whether it can be reduced to an argument in some particular formal system, the answer is also *yes*, but that’s not terribly relevant to actual mathematical practice. If $P(k)$ is the statement that $\{u_i:i\le k\}\cup\{w_i:i>k\}$ spans $V$, and $Q(k)$ is the statement $k\le n\to P(k)$, it’s a proof by induction that $Q(k)$ holds for all $k\ge 0$.